# Breaking line in shadow box

Tags: boxes, box, shadows

I am going to write **Definitions: Least element, Greatest element, minimal element, maximal element** in a shadow box but the line exceeds the page margin. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{centernot}  
\usepackage{fancybox}   
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}   
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8289}{}  
\begin{document}  
       text  
\par 
\shadowbox{\textbf{Definitions: Upper bound, Least Upper Bound, Lower Bound, Greatest Lower Bound}}  
\par \hspace{0.3cm}  
  text  
\end{document}
```

How do I break the long line within shadow box?

Comment: You are already loading `tcolorbox`, so why don't you use it, instead of – the rather old – `fancybox`?

Comment: @DG' because i'm using shadow box for every 'Definition'. `tcolorbox` isn't providing me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the `fancybox` documentation (page 5):

> Entire paragraphs or other vertical mode material such as displayed equations can be nested in a \parbox or minipage.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fancybox}   

\begin{document}  

 \shadowbox{%
   \parbox{\textwidth}{%
     \bfseries
      Definitions: Upper bound, Least Upper Bound, Lower Bound, Greatest Lower Bound}}

 \shadowbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \bfseries
        Definitions: Upper bound, Least Upper Bound,\par Lower Bound, Greatest Lower Bound}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why is it not working when I write `\shadowbox{%\parbox{\textwidth}{%\bfseries Definitions: Upper bound, Least Upper Bound, Lower Bound, Greatest Lower Bound}}` in  a single line?

Comment: Because the first `%` makes all following code invisible or "commented". Your code is  equivalent to `\shadowbox{`, which returns an error

Comment: what does `\bfseries` do?